# Adding a CV in to a simple oscillator

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit, oscillator, vco

I am using an XR2206 IC to make a simple oscillator module. The documentation shows that it has a VCO as a part of the IC, and uses a variable resistor loop and a capacitor loop to control frequency.

[image: XR2206 internal diagram]

My question is: How could I make a toggle, such that I can switch the IC between being controlled by the pots and caps and being controlled by a CV out device, e.g. keyboard? I would appreciate simple wording, as I'm not comprehensively educated on EE.

Comment: A keyboard isn't a CV out device. If you want to use keys then you'll need a serial decoder and a DAC converter to get an analogue voltage out. This side of the project is more troublesome than your basic requirement for some kind of toggle switch.

Comment: Sorry I meant a CV out-enabled MIDI controller type thing. What about the switch? Where should the CV signal be coming into the circuit?